# WordPress inserting "css" in to background image folder url

Tags: css, wordpress, directory

I have a recent WP install that is inserting /css/ in to the url of some background images. When it should be /theme/images/image.png, I get "/theme/css/images/images.png" in the browser inspector. I don't even have any folders in the css folder; the images folder is on the same level.

I have no idea where this is coming from. I've tried all possible url's (images/, ./images, and ../images) other than hardcoding it in, but I should need to do that.

This is a custom theme that's a child of the Whiteboard theme.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I may have been putting my background images in the wrong section. I'm dealing with bad code that I didn't do...and me being new at it. :P I'll keep this open until I'm sure this was it.

Answer (score 0):

Paths specified inside a CSS style sheet are relative *to that style sheet*.

So most likely, you have a CSS file with

```
background-image: url("images/images.png")
```

style URLs in it.

The solution might be to change the URLs to

```
background-image: url("../images/images.png")
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and no dice. even when I start with '../' it just sticks that in the url. So it ends up as 'theme/../css/images/image.png'.

Comment: @Kyle where do the URLs come from?

Comment: Yes, you'd think it would be relative wouldn't you!? But that doesn't seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Is the theme using `get_bloginfo('template_url')` or something like `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` ? If the background image is being set in PHP somewhere, this could be the issue. More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

If you're setting it in CSS, you might try a relative URL like Pekka suggests, or a root relative URL like `/wp-content/themes/[theme name]/`